# How to recognize object with a given shape

Tags: opencv

I want to recognize known object using `OpenCV` through following steps:

1. Using `Background Sub-tractor` getting the foreground objects.
2. Finding the contours and iterate over top level.

Now while I am iterating the contours I want to match every contour with a given shape and draw the a rectangle if the contour was matched with the given shape.

Here I also want to say; the given shape size is something like 100x100 px, but the contour size maybe smaller or bigger then the shape size, then size must not affect the result of matching.

Before I have used `Template Matching`, the result was not so good because even the given object was not in frame, it will also detect something other. And `matchShapes()` function, but the size can affect the result.

Now is there any good way to perform such job? If someone knows please tell me the way to do this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Shape context descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_context) are often used in object recognition, shape context is intended to be a way of describing shapes that allows for measuring shape similarity and the recovering of point correspondences.

Here is an example in OpenCV:
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/shape_example.cpp

Comment: I tried that shape_example.cpp, (opencv3.2, MacOs). It is not giving result as expected.